# Python: Pearson's r

Tags: python, correlation, data-analysis, pearson

So this is my code for calculating the correlation between two variables using pearson's r.

```
def correlation(x, y):
    std_x = (x - x.mean()) / x.std(ddof=0)
    std_y = (y - y.mean()) / y.std(ddof=0)

    return (std_x * std_y).mean()
```

I understand that in order to do so, one needs to:

1. Standardize each variable
2. Multiply each pair of values, and take the average

Which brings me to my question, why is the below line used:

```
std_x = (x - x.mean()) / x.std(ddof=0)
```

instead of simply:

```
r = (x.std(ddof=0)*y.std(ddof=0))/len(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you get confused on the formula of Pearson's coefficient. Say you have two random variables X and Y. Then Pearson's coefficient is defined as

`r = Cov(X, Y)/(s_X*s_Y)`

Where `Cov(X, Y)` is the covariance between X and Y, and `s_Y` and `s_Y` their standard deviation.

`Cov(X, Y) = E[(X-E[X])*(Y - E[Y])]`

Where `E[Z]` designs the expected value of the random variable `Z`.

Ok, now we have the formula, so how to compute that. Actually you can't since you don't have access to the *real* standard deviations and *real* expected values. Instead, what we usually do is compute the sample correlation coefficient, which is based on this formula but replacing the *real* values by the values given by estimators.

A natural (minimum variance non biased) estimator for the expected values in the formula, is simply the mean (given by `np.mean`), and samewise, the right estimator for the standard deviation is the empirical standard deviation given by `np.std`.

So putting it all together, the formula would become

`r = np.mean((x-np.mean(x))*(y-np.mean(y)))/(np.std(x)*np.std(y))`

which is actually the same as

`np.mean(X*Y)`

where `X = (x-np.mean(x))/np.std(x)`and `Y = (y-np.mean(y))/np.std(y)`

Comment: Thanks!! Cleared up the confusion